# Bot nao digita valores dentro da função def, usando comando de send keys com o selenium driver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Estou criando um projeto automatizado usando o selenium driver. Estou iniciando com o Python na verdade, e quando crio a função def abaixo, o mesmo esta localizando os elementos mas não está digitando os valores. Se eu faço o código direto sem o def, ele digita, mas dentro da função def não está digitando. Acredito eu que esteja deixando de fazer algo importante.

Segue o código abaixo.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=r'C:\Users\rogerio.junior\Documents\Projetos 
Python\Meu_Progama\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://pegasus/Rekrut/Logon/LoginManual')

sleep(2)

browser.maximize_window()

sleep(2)
def Entrar(Login, Senha):
    browser.find_element_by_id('Login').send_keys(Login)
    browser.find_element_by_id('Senha').send_keys(Senha)
    browser.find_element_by_class_name('btn').click()

    Entrar("Valorx", "Valory")
```

Answer (score 0):

Se a endentação estiver conforme a pergunta postada, ajuste a seu código para:

```
def Entrar(Login, Senha):
    browser.find_element_by_id('Login').send_keys(Login)
    browser.find_element_by_id('Senha').send_keys(Senha)
    browser.find_element_by_class_name('btn').click()

Entrar("Valorx", "Valory")
```

Você deve "voltar" (remover) 4 espaços na chamada da função `Entrar`.

Comment: Deu Certo, era so colocar a funcao que havia criado de forma correta entao. Muito Obrigado.